# File management for profile pictures

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image-processing, concurrency

I'm bulding an ASP.NET website where the users can upload their profile picture. I store these images under the App_Data folder and the file paths in the Users table.

So, the question is how should I update the user's profile picture? I mean, what happens if I overwrite the previous file and at the same time a request arrives to get the picture. Should I have some concurrency management?
My best solution is generating a file name for the new image(the user record in the database would be updated with this new path as well) and store the old path somewhere else, in order to delete it later. 
Is this a good idea?

Comment: I assume the image would just go blank. I don't think there would be a problem. If there was, you can upload the image with a new random filename such as a GUID, then update the database table. Then you can delete the old image.

Comment: Yes, this is my idea too.

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do in my case.

1. Creates a folder in my project with path ~/uploads/images. Here images is my concerned folder which is under uploads and uploads is in root.
2. While saving image path to db i use simple

   var dbpath=
       string.Format("~/Uploads/Images/{0}",Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-",string.Empty));
3. And from file upload control `Fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(dbPath));`

If you want to display image over the page from database, either you can use

1. `<asp:Image runat="server" id="immm"></asp:Image> , from code behind imm.ImageUrl = dt.Rows[0]["ImagePath"].ToString"`

2.If its inside grid/repeater, use simply  `<asp:Image runat="server" id="immm" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%'></asp:Image>`

Answer (score 0):

No need to generate new file names. There's a very smart solution.

Alter your Users table and add a Uploadversion field. And overwrite the same file with uploaded file and just increase a upload version field in your Users table.

When your client requests the file, send the path with this version. Client may add this version as fake querystring to src path of your img element.

```
<img src="/[image_route]?[version]" />
```

For ex:

```
<img src="/images/john_doe/photo?16" />
```